# MySQL: query to return the row offset only

Tags: mysql

Given a table

```
 field1  |  field2

 abc     |  1
 efg     |  30
 etc     |  10
```

I would like to run a query like `SELECT offset() FROM table WHERE field1 = 'etc' ORDER BY field2 DESC`

Such an imaginary query should return `2` (ordering by `field2 desc`, `field1 = etc` is the second row)

Any clean way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to rank the rows by some metric, and then return the rank of certain rows?

Comment: exactly. sorry, but my english is a bad beast.

Comment: So `SELECT offset() FROM table WHERE field1 = 'abc' ORDER BY field2 DESC` should return 0 and field1 = 'efg' should return 1?

Comment: yes, or 1 and 2, i don't really care. however i solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by row offset that: The rank of the row after ordering the results with `order by field2 DESC` which has `field1 = 'etc'`, Then you could do something like:

```
SET @rowRank = 0; 
SELECT Sub.rowRank
FROM
(
    SELECT *, (@rowRank := @rowRank + 1) as rowRank
    FROM TableName
    ORDER BY field2 DESC
) AS Sub
WHERE Sub.field1 = 'etc'
```

This should return 2.

Comment: is such expression `select *, any` valid?

Comment: @triclosan, Yes, it is Valid.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table outer 
WHERE field1 != 'etc' 
AND field2 <= (SELECT MAX(inner.field2) 
  FROM table inner 
  WHERE inner.field1 = outer.field1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) 
from table 
where field2 > {field2 of the row to search the offset for, in this case, 10};
```

Comment: Because it's not a real query.

Comment: I don't think so.
DB::select(DB::expr('COUNT(newsgroup_id) AS rank'))->from('newsgroup')->where('freshness', '>', $newsgroup['freshness'])->execute()->get('rank')